# SQL ORACLE SET OPERATOR

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a practice asking to show the job_id and department_id to the departments 10,20,50 and order them in specific order as 10,50,20

My select statement

```
select job_id,department_id
from employees
INTERSECT
select job_id,department_id
from employees
where department_id IN (10,20,50)
ORDER BY 2,CASE department_id WHEN 10 then 1
                            WHEN 50 then 2
                            WHEN 20 then 3
                            ELSE THEN 4
                            END
```

MESSAGE OUTPUT IS

> ORA-01785: ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

Comment: I don't understand why `intersect` is being used for this query.

Comment: because the practice requested to do this query by using set operate

Comment: . . I don't think this does what you want, even if the code works.  You may want to ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional ordering with a `case` expression:

```
select job_id, department_id
from employees
where department id in (10, 20, 50)
order by 
    case department_id 
        when 10 then 1
        when 50 then 2
        when 20 then 3
    end,
    job_id
```

This will order the record according to your custom department order, then by `job_id`.

Since you are using Oracle, the `order by` clause can be shortened using `decode()`:

```
order by decode(department_id, 10, 1, 50, 2, 20, 3), job_id
```

Note: I don't see the point for `intersect` in this query, so I removed it; but if you need if for some reason, the above `order by` clause would still remain the same.

Comment: the practice requested to do this query by using set operate and I did what you mentioned to me but I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your statement. In the ORDER BY clause you should use

```
CASE department_id WHEN 10 then 1
                        WHEN 50 then 2
                        WHEN 20 then 3
                        ELSE 4
                        END
```

instead of

```
CASE department_id WHEN 10 then 1
                        WHEN 50 then 2
                        WHEN 20 then 3
                        ELSE THEN 4
                        END
```

Basically, you shouldn't put `THEN` in the `ELSE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the `case` statement in your query.

You have not properly used the `case` statement, there was a missing value in the `ELSE` clause.

Also, `INTERSECT` is not needed for the requirement mentioned by you.

You can simply go for something like this to consider 50 as 11 so that the 10-50-20 (converted to 10-11-20) order is maintained.

```
SELECT
    JOB_ID,
    DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM
    EMPLOYEES
WHERE
    DEPARTMENT_ID IN (
        10,
        20,
        50
    )
ORDER BY
    DECODE(DEPARTMENT_ID, 50, 11, DEPARTMENT_ID) , JOB_ID
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I found the solution  as use this query as a table and retrieve the results from it then order them in specific order

Comment: the syntax is SELECT job_id,department_id
from
(
select job_id,department_id
from employees
intersect 
select job_id, department_id 
from employees
where department_id in (10,20,50)
)
ORDER BY decode(department_id,10,1,50,2,20,3,4)

Comment: Glad that it helped you.!!